# Blogger Images Compression using WebP

Tags: blogger, webp

I want to change my thumbnails to use the latest image compression technology. Blogger does provide it using the URL parameters
for example this is my thumbnail:

```
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/s350/image-name.jpg
```

and I want to transform it to WebP format by adding `rw` so it will look like this

```
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/s350-rw/image-name.jpg
```

Blogger WebP Images use an additional -rw beside s350 in the image URL.
Currently I have this data tag in place.

```
expr:src = 'resizeImage (data: post.thumbnailUrl, 350)'
```

Please, give some references to pass the `-rw` parameter in this data tag. I'm unable to find in any documentation (official or unofficial)

PS: I do not want any JavaScript solution, I know it can be done easily :/

Comment: Does this help https://www.techandbio.com/how-to-serve-images-in-webp-format-in-blogger/ ?

Comment: @M.Abdeldayem I'm aware of that, changing each images url is not convenient for end user. Thats why i'm looking for an official way, some sort of Data Tags from Blogger template engine.

Answer (score 0):

How To Convert Blogger Images To WebP Format

This is how you do it:

1. Log into your Blogger Dashboard.
2. Click on your blog post which you want to change the JPEG or PNG format to WebP.
3. Next click on the pencil icon on the left hand side of the post editor.
4. Then click on "HTML view".
5. Then look for the image code, which looks something like this:

6. Look for "s1600".
7. There are two of them in there (in bold).
8. Just after s1600, add -rw.
9. This is what it looks like after the changes:

> Note: Some of you might not have “s1600”. You may see  codes like:
> “s200”, “s320”, “s400”, “s640” or some other digits.

You just add “-rw” after any of these codes.

10. After adding the -rw, click the "Update" button.
11. That's all.
    All your images will be converted to web format and your blog will super load fast, making blog load fast is one of the top [3 Things You Should Do To Make Your Blog Be On The First Page On Search Engine](https://www.nairaalert.com.ng/2022/04/3-things-you-should-do-to-make-your.html)

Comment: Please read the question, its already mentioned that `-rw` parameter can do it, but how we can pass it to the `data` tags of Blogger template engine

Answer (score -2):

I hope you can find this helpful.

you can use this javascript code to convert blogger images to webp.

```js
// image optimization 

var myIMG = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var x =0 ; x < myIMG.length; x++) {
 var imgSRC = myIMG[x].src; 
var imgSRC_width = myIMG[x].width; 
var imgSRC_height = myIMG[x].height; 

   var  mypin = String(imgSRC.match(/\/s72-c\//));
                        imgSRC = replaceAll(imgSRC, mypin, "/w" + imgSRC_width + "-h" + imgSRC_height + "-p/" + "-rw");
imgSRC = imgSRC.replace(/png/gim,"webp");
imgSRC = imgSRC.replace(/jpeg/gim,"webp");
imgSRC = imgSRC.replace(/jpg/gim,"webp");
myIMG[x].src= imgSRC;

console.log(imgSRC);}
```

This code gets all images in your blog and converts them to webp.

Have fun!

Comment: quote from the question: `I do not want any JavaScript solution, I know it can be done easily :/`.

Comment: Ok, this what I know. 
hope to find a better solution.

Comment: @MohamedGad Thank you for taking your time for the answer. but as Alex. T pointed out Javascript will not help. The goal is to serve nextgen images format for speed.

Comment: What is the benefit of doing this? As client will have to load the whole image first, then converting it to webp doesn't make sense in this senerio.